# Questions about database secondary indexes

Tags: mysql

When a secondary index (or secondary index) is created in a table where there is no primary key or primary key index, what hangs under the leaf node of the secondary index?

Comment: If there's no primary key, the the database will create an internal clustered key and use that.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html